# How can I programmatically stop or start a website in IIS (6.0 and 7.0) using MsBuild?

Tags: c#, iis-7, msbuild, iis-6, web-deployment

I have Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6.0) and Windows Server 2008 (IIS 7.0) servers, and I use MSBuild for deploying web applications.

I need to do a safe deploy, and do this:

1. Stop a website in IIS 6 (or an Application in IIS 7), not stop AppPool.
2. Check if the website is stopped; not running.
3. If the website is stopped, do another task for deploy.
4. Start the website IIS 6 (or Application in IIS 7),

How can I achieve this?

Update: Key for me: IIS6WebSite and IIS6AppPool (and for IIS7), do wait for stopped status when try Stop Website or AppPool?

When I execute Stop Action for Website (or Stop Action for AppPool), I need be sure 100% that Website is stopped, and then, and only if Website is Stopped, I can execute other targets.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is something like [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/). It provides tasks to start/stop IIS web sites (for II6 see [Iis6WebSite](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.2.0/html/2849df01-25a8-6f99-5a0c-0fa7a6df5084.htm)).

Comment: +1 while everything here "works", this is the best way if you are just using MSBuild.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Key for me: Iis6WebSite and IIs6AppPool (and for IIS7), do wait for stopped status when try Stop WebSite or AppPool ?

Comment: Using MSBuild Extension Pack., how can I know the status (Started, Stopped, ...) of WebSite or AppPool (IIS6) ??

Comment: @alhambraeidos - One option is to use the HttpWebRequest task to see if you get a 404 back (which I guess would assume the site is down/stopped)?

Answer (score 56):

By adding a reference to `Microsoft.Web.Administration` (which can be found in`X:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`, or your systems equivalent) you can achieve nice managed control of the situation with IIS7, as sampled below:

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = new ServerManager();
            var site = server.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Default Web Site");
            if (site != null)
            {
                //stop the site...
                site.Stop();
                if (site.State == ObjectState.Stopped)
                {
                    //do deployment tasks...
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not stop website!");
                }
                //restart the site...
                site.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find website!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously tailor this to your own requirements and through your deployment build script execute the resulting application.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Can I use Microsoft.Web.Administration for Win2003-IIS 6 and VS 2008 .NET 3.5 ??

Comment: No, this will only work for IIS7. You will need a different approach for IIS6, such as using `WMI` or `DirectoryServices`.

Comment: Note `Microsoft.Web.Administration` can also be found on `NuGet`

Comment: Do you have any idea of running the site through winforms cefsharp

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! In my case I found that I also needed to stop and start the application pool.

Answer (score 2):

- [Write a script](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=start+stop+iis+website+programmatically+site%3Astackoverflow.com), e.g. PowerShell, which will stop/start IIS web site programmatically relying on command-line argument, e.g. `start-stop.ps1 /stop 1`
- Put it into MsBuild script as a custom step

---

Check [this](http://terrapinstation.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/restart-iis-application-pool-from-aspnet-page/) to find out how to restart IIS AppPool

[IIS WMI objects reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525265%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Just to note IIS7 has a managed API, rather than relying on `DirectoryServices` or `WMI`: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/284/using-managed-apis-in-iis-7/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: any sample msbuild and powershell ?. I need stop and start WebSites in iis6, (or sites in iis7), not appPool.

Answer (score 0):

So you have your answer above for IIS7. What you're missing is IIS6. So here you go. This is using a COM interop object as that's all that is available for IIS 6. Also, because it's in vb, you'll have to figure out how to convert it. **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16686/A-C-alternative-for-the-Visual-Basic-GetObject-fun** should get you on the right track. you could also create a vb project just for this code but that's kind of silly.

```
Dim WebServiceObj As Object
dim IisSiteId as Integer = 0
WebServiceObj = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/" & IisSiteId)
WebServiceObj.Stop()
WebServiceObj.Start()
```