# IIS API - How to Stop / Unload specific IIS Application

Tags: iis, web-deployment

How to stop/unload a specific IIS Application (hosted within a specific Site) in order to release the server's resources?

The [IIS API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx) (Microsoft.Web.Administration) seems only to allow stopping the entire Site:

[Stop/Start WebSite in IIS (6.0 and 7.0) programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958799/)

**UPDATED:**

I have managed to resolve this issue via an alternative way:

[Configure an Application Pool to Recycle after Reaching Maximum Virtual Memory Usage (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732519%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

As a result, a particular pool is recycling automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the site in it's own application pool, then just recycle that pool

Comment: I have updated my answer. In any case, your answer is useful. I have accepted in order to close the issue.