# how to get start a iis website and get performance of that web site using

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Recently when i try to start a web site using the following code it is returning null
and i have getting all the website using severmanager object Iam getting all the visual web projects in asp.net web page[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958799/stop-start-an-website-in-iis-6-0-and-7-0-programatically-using-msbuild)

how to resolve this issue[image: output of code snippet] and can i get all the performance data raw values from iis performance counters at a time?

```
ServerManager IIS = new ServerManager();
        List<string> iissites = new List<string>();

        foreach (Site site in IIS.Sites)
        {
            iissites.Add(site.Name.ToString());
        }
        foreach (Site site in IIS.Sites)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Concat
            //(
            //    site.Name, " , ",
            //    site.Id, " , ",
            //    //site.State, " , ",
            //    site.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath
            //));
            Console.WriteLine(site.Name.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback, I have solved my problem by creating a web service in visual studio 2010 and linking ,i  Mean i have a web reference to the asp.net project and i have called that web service methods in my asp.net web application. and now it is working fine ! 
 Thanks and Regards 
Suresh chinna