# Stopping IIS in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis

I am using C# to automate some procedures

1. Start IIS
2. Open Internet Explorer at a specific address on specific port
3. User closes the browser
4. Stop IIS

I am stuck on step four as I have to use the same port for other procedures after.

I created a thread that will be called to start IIS:

```
public class MyThread
{
    //thread to start IIS
    public static void Thread1()
    {
        //thread for running IIS
        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/path:""c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles"" /vpath:/asp.netwebadminfiles /port:61569 /clr:4.0 /ntlm";
            //proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit(); 
            //output from the process run
            Console.Out.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

The code to open IE is:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));
        thread1.Start();
        using (Process proc1 = new Process())
        {
            proc1.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";
            proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = @"http://localhost:61569/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\Users\"+userName+@"\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NN\&applicationUrl=/";
            proc1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc1.Start();
            proc1.WaitForExit();
            //output from the process run
            Console.Out.WriteLine(proc1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

I have tried to create another thread to Kill/Abort the original thread, but that doesn't work.  I also tried to write "Q" at the end of the console, but that also does nothing.

Any ideas of how I can stop IIS when the browser is closed?

Comment: Not exactly sure what the problem you are having is; does `WaitForExit` return properly when IE closes? And may I ask what your IISExpress thing does? It's possible there's a more direct way to do what you are attempting.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958799/stop-start-an-website-in-iis-6-0-and-7-0-programatically-using-msbuild

Comment: Assuming your application is running as an elevated privilege level have you considered executing this command line `net stop w3svc /Y` from your code?

Comment: Try looking at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21120/Stop-Start-IIS-Website-in-NET-C

Comment: `iisreset /stop` or `appcmd stop site "sitename"` (you didn't say which version of IIS, the latter is preferred in IIS 7+).

Comment: It might be easier (more straightforward) to script this type of thing in PowerShell, if you're not constrained to using C#.

Comment: Killing processes is the wrong level. At *leat* you should be restarting the service (which is trivial in .NET). Better, use an IIS library.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be killing the process to stop IIS. Pulling the rug underneath it isn't a great thing to do, and besides, if the service has any restart actions then it will start right back up again.

Use a ServiceController (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) to start and stop the appropriate service.

There are other ways to control IIS such as using WMI (which I believe is now deprecated), however using a ServiceController should be sufficient for your task.