# How to programmatically stop an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exit

I wonder if there is a way to shutdown/exit/stop an ASP.NET MVC web application from code? In my `global.asax.cs` --> `Application_Start()` method I am checking some prerequisites like a working database connection etc., if one of them is not met, I want the application to shutdown and give an error. How can I do that? Is it even possible at all or can this only be done from "outside" (e.g. IIS management console or similar)?

Comment: possibly dublicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843418/how-can-i-programmatically-stop-the-current-website) can help aslo

Comment: That solved it, thanks!

Comment: upvote if help ;)