# Closing IIS Express in Command Line

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, iis-express

I want to launch and stop IIS Express services for testing purposes using the command line in my .NET application, however iisreset had no impact on my iis express servicees and I couldn't find a way to solve my problem.

The interesting thing is, this works: [image]

but when I try to replicat exactly this in my code, the stopping of the service with the button click Q doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\");
        //var applicationPath = 
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(@".\iisexpress /path:c:\users\<User-Name>\source\repos\pinkey-depot\pinkey-Depot\ /port:62008");
        
        _driver.Url = ("http://localhost:62008/Customers/Create");
        //this should pass
        Assert.True(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("EMail")).Displayed);
        Assert.True(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Firstname")).Displayed);
        
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("q"); //seems to have no effect

        _driver.Url = ("http://localhost:62008/Customers/Create");
        //this should fail
        Assert.True(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("EMail")).Displayed);
        Assert.True(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Firstname")).Displayed);

        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.Kill();
```

I have spent quite a time on trying to fix this problem and I can't believe there is no way to do what I intend.

Comment: Maybe you can find useful this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975707/stopping-and-starting-iis-in-c-sharp, instead of using command line.