# How to start process in background onclick of button in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created one button and on click of button I want to reset my IIS from command prompt in background..

This is how I tried:

```
namespace Demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Arguments = @" /C IISRESET"
            };
            Process.Start(psi);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like not working. What should be the correct way? I'm Very new in this. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: `/C`, not `/ C` (check the space)

Comment: ok.. I will correct that.. Rest code is correct ??@Cid

Comment: I think this will need to run with admin rights to work (someone correct me if I'm wrong!). Also, if you're using IIS7 or later there's a managed interface for this so you don't *have* to run an EXE to do it; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959268/106159) for details.